# RSpec giving undefined method `key?' for controller testing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, rspec-rails

Trying to test my controller with RSpec how ever I am getting this error:

[image]

I looked at couple of stackoverflows but couldn't find the answer:

[StackOverflowOne](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15066417/view-stub-in-rails-partial-rspec-gives-undefined-method-view-context)

[StackOverflowTwo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27902364/rspec-post-results-in-undefined-method-key-for-createsymbol)

[StackOverflowThree](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31765624/rspec-undefined-method-key)

can some one please explain this error to me?

This is my Test case:
[image]

This is my controller:
[image]

This is my model:
[image]

Comment: Please provide actual code instead of images. Copy/paste is actually easier for both the asker and the answerer compared to posting code as images like you have

Comment: I am more than a little surprised you can have a valid table named '''Application'''

Answer (score 1, accepted):

instead of `post :create, app` you need to `post :create, id: app`

with this exception, ruby is trying to tell you that you passed something that is not quacking like a hash into the `post` method, so it does not have a `key?` method on `app`.

i would like to recommend [this article about debugging rails in development](http://nofail.de/2013/10/debugging-rails-applications-in-development/) to you. it might help you improve your debugging skills.

another note: if you post a question to stackoverflow, you should paste real code instead of screenshots so that it's searchable for others and easy to copy and paste into answers.

Comment: @phoet Thank you very much for answering the question and pointing me to your article I am half way through and it is very useful.